# NETPLAN "DESTINATION HOST UNREACHABLE" Ubuntu 20.04.6 desktop

Tags: 20.04, network-manager, sudo, netplan, ifconfig

I'm quite new to Ubuntu and I'm trying to configure my netplan file.
when I set the configuration in my `/etc/netplan/01.-network-manager.yaml` there seems to be an issue after i have apply the setting (pinging Ip addresses).

I have already done `netplan generate` ,`netplan try` and `netplan apply` but for some reason my ping won't work. even when i try ping locally, it seems to be doing the samething.

What I'm trying to do is install packages using the `sudo` command but due too it not able to connect or reach the gateway, i need to fix this issue first.

can someone help please?

Ps this is for Ubuntu 20.04.6 desktop

Here is my configuration

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
     dhcp4: false
     addresses:
      - 192.168.27.68/24
     nameservers:
      addresses: [192.168.27.13,8.8.8.8]
     routes:
      - to: default
        via: 192.168.27.13
```

Here is the results

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.27.68 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.27.68 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.27.68 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Comment: Ok, thanks you.

Comment: I have deleted the question, I don't have Intermitted connection, and I installed Ubuntu via CMD, I'm pretty sure if your familiar with Ubuntu will know you can install it via CMD. but thank you

Comment: Okay thank you, I did Install it with ```wsl --install``` using command prompt. Next time i will be sure to add more details to the question

Comment: Virtualization (like Hyper-V and Virtualbox and others) provide a *virtual* network interface. But that network is internal, it's not your LAN. The Host application (on Windows) controls the virtual network and controls access of Guests (like WSL) to the real-world LAN. Your output suggests that Ubuntu cannot see the real 192.168.27.* LAN because it can see only the virtual network provided by WSL.

Comment: I see, that make more sense now, Thank you :)

Comment: A stock install of WSL + Ubuntu Desktop avoids the wrong-network trap by using Network Address Translation (NAT): Windows operates a (virtual) router to connect the two networks. The easiest way to use that is to NOT use networkd, which is for static IP addresses on servers. Revert to using NetworkManager, which is designed for more dynamic environments. Also revert any changes you made to the WSL host.

Comment: I'm not a WSL expert, so I'm going to leave more detail to someone else. Lots of good WSL troubleshooting information at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/